# Google Play Movies with restricted accounts

Tags: restricted-profiles

I've created a Restricted account for my daughter to use my Pixel C. I've enabled Google Play Movies. However,  when I open the app none of my purchases are visible. This seems contrary to how it is supposed to work, and I can't see how this app would work with Restricted profiles at all. Any advice appreciated.

My end desire is that I can let her watch movies, but lock the rest down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it Google Play Videos was defaulting to my other Google account which has no content. So I just needed to switch accounts and it worked perfectly.